# Upload file button doesn't work site wide

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a site-wide issue where the media file upload button isn't working. By this, I mean, I press `Upload Files`, and nothing happens.

I have checked all the usual suspects, cleared cache, reindexed data. I also checked the folder permissions which look fine.

This video shows the error in action

https://youtu.be/qrG_0l5hAYM

Comment: check if you have javascript errors

Comment: did you check in different browsers ?

Comment: Hi, I've checked for javascript errors, can't see any and yes tried in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox. Also checked to make sure they all have flash installed and active for my site. Still no joy